# Why past form of a verb is used instead of passive past?

Tags: pragmatics

Sending an email with GMail app on Android in the Airplane mode produces the following message:

> キューに追加しました "(the app) added (the message) to the queue"

Switching to English interface yields:

> Queued (short for "The message has been queued" - I believe this is how most English speakers would interpret "queued").

The question is why the Japanese version is not passive past? Is it possible that 追加する an intransitive verb, and from what I observed, most Japanese intransitive verbs are best translated as English passive voice.

Answer (score 2):

No, 追加しました is transitive. And it's more natural than passive either if you regard that you are the causative and the app is the causee or that you are the agent unless you are the patient who can't control what's happening.